# Is it possible to prevent getDisplayMedia from changing focus?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, mediastream

When I use navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() it will give the user a selection of windows and tabs to choose from [media stream API selection choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M96AP.png)
When the use makes a selection chrome will navigate to the tab/screen/window the user selected to share with the getDisplayMidia()

Is there a way for the user to select the screen to share without chrome navigating to it but rather staying on the same webpage?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that the screen that you are sharing must be focused in order to be grabbed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.